# If $f(x+a)$ is irreducible over $F$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Actually we can prove the statement in the reverse way.

Here $a$ is non zero element, $F$ is a field.

Suppose $f(x)$ is reducible then $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, then $f(x+a)= g(x+a) h(x+a)$.

But I can't understand what it exactly wants to convey.

It's an exercise problem from Joseph Gallion Algebra under Factorization of Polynomials.

Comment: There really are situations where it is easier to prove $f(x+1)$ is irreducible, and then this result shows $f(x)$ is irreducible too. The simplest family of examples is $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ in $\mathbf Q[x]$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: Pretty trivial, but sometimes, when one is using the Eisenstein Irreducibility Criterion, this can be useful.  Here is a totally unserious example. Suppose we want to show that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over the rationals. Replace $x$ by $x+1$. We get $x^2+3x+3$, to which Eisenstein applies.